# How to compose an observable with a task that might need to be re-run?

Tags: c#, rx.net

Suppose I have an async method that runs a query
and returns a set of results:

```
Task<IEnumerable<Foo>> FetchResultSet();
```

And I have an observable that fires whenever the
result set needs to be fetched again:

```
IObservable<Unit> NeedToRefetch;
```

What I want is:

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<Foo>>
```

Which would (1) run the query and yield an initial 
result set, and (2) each time `NeedToRefetch` fires, run
the query again and yield another result set.

What's the best way to compose this observable?

If I didn't need that initial result set, I could do this:

```
NeedToRefetch
    .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => FetchResultSet()))
    .Concat();
```

So to make sure that the query gets run at least once, I could
do this:

```
Observable.Return(Unit.Default)
    .Merge(NeedToRefetch)
    .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => FetchResultSet()))
    .Concat();
```

But then I started reading about cold and hot observables and I
wondered if instead I should do something like this:

```
var initial = Observable.FromAsync(() => FetchResultSet());
var later = NeedToRefetch
    .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => FetchResultSet()))
    .Concat();
initial
    .Merge(later);
```

And then I wondered if this is a case where I am supposed to use
`Observable.Create`.

And I then I stopped wondering and wrote this question.

Comment: Hi Eric, can you rephrase your question to be a bit more objective? Right now, "what's the best way" is an opinion-based question... we don't even know what metric you're measuring "best" by, and primarily opinion-based questions are off-topic here. What problem with your code, specifically and objectively, would using cold/hot observables solve? Will your code run fine without them? Those are a couple things to consider when constructing a question that might help you solve it yourself.

Comment: I assume you are a bot?  If I just remove the word "best" do I avoid the trigger words?

Comment: No, and please don't be rude. What's the best way to do anything? What do you mean best? Fastest? Fewest LOC? Most secure? Easiest to read by another human? Smallest file size? Why is whichever metric you choose the "best" one? In case you can't tell, I'm trying to help you improve your question so that you're more likely to get a (better) answer.

Comment: @Erik what's about second option but without .Concat?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you're almost there. You can use your original approach. To make it run once immediately you can include a `StartWith()`:

```
NeedToRefetch
    .StartWith(Unit.Default)
    .Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(() => FetchResultSet()))
    .Concat();
```